# Show that if $G$ is connected and it has two spanning trees with differente edges, then $G$ has a spanning graph eulerian

Tags: graph-theory

i need help with this:

Show that if $G$ is connected and it has two spanning trees with differente edges, then $G$ has a spanning subgraph eulerian

spanning tree: spanning subgraph of $G$ and it's a tree

I really need to solve it, can you give a clue, please? thansk!

Comment: Do you mean that it has two spanning trees with no edges in common? Or just two different spanning trees that might have *some* edges in common?

Comment: sorry, with no edges in common

Comment: The earlier question has two usable and quite different answers; I especially like the later one (by **Asa**).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If a graph is connected and all the vertices have even degree, then it has at least one Euler's circuit.